# Elasticsearch : Hight disk read + slow indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk

I use elasticsearch to index 200GB of simple structered document (without text field, without nested document).
I Observe periodic degradation on indexing rate during at least one hour and hight disk read io.
I use bulk request with refresh_interval = -1, Monitoring not show cpu or memory problem.
I suspect flush or merge process but with monitoring i do not see that merge or flush take a lot of time.

I use one node with 5 shard, Memory 8GB and 4 cpu (disk hdd).

Can i have constant indexing rate with elasticsearch if i change configuration ? How to monitore which process of elasticsearch do massive disk read (80mb/s during at least 1 hour every time)

thanks

Comment: For starters, if you have only 1 node, why do you have 5 shards?  Also: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html

Comment: Because shard has limit (index lucene limit), i choose use of rollover with small index having on shard.